# Adding Text with the NumberFormat VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, format

I have worte below code and now i want to add text with date and Time like this.

```
Last Update on: 3/12/2021  6:38:43 AM
```

I tried with below code but its not working any help will be appreciated.

```
With Sheet9.Range("H8")
.Value = Now()
.NumberFormat = "Last update on: " & "mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Last update on: " isn't really a valid format.
You could try to add the text in after the formatting.
Usint Range.Text instead of .Value should retain any formatting.

```
With Sheet9.Range("H8")
   .Value = Now()
   .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
   .Value = "Last update on: " & .Text
End With
```

If we are going to have it as a text anyway, we can employ FunThomas method to do it all on one line.

```
.Value = Format(Now(), """Last update on: "" mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM")
```

Comment: Just need to use in a single cell. Thank you very much.

Comment: That modifies the content of the cell, after the code runs, the cell no longer contain a date but a string.

Comment: @FunThomas That is very true.

Comment: Yes i do not need a cell to be  date format just current time and date should be pasted along with the  text nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

The number format in Excel (not VBA) would look like `"Last Update on " dd/ mmm yyyy`- the fix text needs to be put into quotes.

When setting the number format using VBA, you need to tell VBA (not Excel) that you want to have a quote within a string. You do this by double the quotes. Look at the following statement: The first quote tells VBA that a string starts. The 2nd and 3rd quote tells VBA that you don't want to end the string but to put a quote character inside the string.

```
.NumberFormat = """Last Update on "" dd/ mmm yyyy"
```

Comment: Yes i was on mistaken thank you for the corrections.